# Persisting OneToOne relation Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm, persistence, one-to-one

I have an issure related with persisting an OneToOne Doctrine2 relation.

Overview:

I have two entities: UserEntity (the profile) and UserDataEntity (user's data). Each UserEntity would have UserDataEntity(but it is not required), but each UserDataEntity must have UserEntity which reffers to.

When I'm trying to persist UserEntity i receives an error:

> SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 BŁĄD:  pusta wartość w kolumnie "id" narusza ograniczenie wymaganej wartości
>   That means that column "id" in User's table cannot be null. It is confusing, because this column has autogenerated primary key strategy assigned.

Below there are my entities:

```
/**
 * A user.
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class UserEntity extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ModuleAdmin\Entity\TradesmanDataEntity", inversedBy="parent", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="data_id")
     */
    protected $data;

    public function setData(UserDataEntity $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
}
```

And user's data entity:

```
/**
 * A user's data.
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users_data")
 */
class UserDataEntity extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ModuleAdmin\Entity\TradesmanEntity", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="data_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $phone;

    /**
     * Provides creation for new empty entity.
     * 
     */
    public function __construct(TradesmanEntity $parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }
}
```

My PostgreSQL database schema looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
);


CREATE TABLE users_data
(
  data_id integer NOT NULL,
  email character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  phone character varying NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT users_data_pkey PRIMARY KEY (data_id ),
  CONSTRAINT users_data_data_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (data_id)
      REFERENCES users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I wold like to keep the constraints in database level, not ORM.

Comment: *"autogenerated primary key strategy assigned"*? I do not see that in your database schema.

Comment: This is PostgreSQL schema, SERIAL indicates (in UserEntity), that default value is next value from the sequence related with the table (equivalent to auto_increment in MySQL). I have just edited my question and mentioned, that schema is PostgreSQL.

Comment: Ah I see. Any reason you added the `NOT NULL` then?

Comment: NOT NULL keeps the database integration in right way in database level. As I mentioned, there won't be UserDataEntity without UserEntity. In addition, NOT NULL is required to create the primary key (in case of UserEntity it it ID of user; in case of UserDataEntiry, column data_id is integer NOT NULL refers to user's id - it is required in fact).

Comment: Having `serial` already has the meaning `NOT NULL`. So I ask why you add it additionally. The error btw is from the database-server layer. You probably should dump the actual query run by doctrine and see if there is something wrong with it.

Comment: `NOT NULL` in user's table has been added automaticaly. I have just added `NOT NULL` manually in user's data table. I have also tried with changing `cascade={"persist"}` with no affect.

Comment: This happened to me weeks ago: when you have a relation between two entities (mainly when both are new entities), one entity expect the ID of the other one and viceversa (like a deathlock). My solution: remove `NOT NULL` from one entity, because doctrine once persist both entities it updates the entity with the ID=NULL with the genered ID from the other one

Comment: Can we see the code php where you try persisting an user?